# Jasmine env is not defined

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jasmine

I'm working on an AngularJS app. I'm trying to do some testing on it. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. I just get an error in my console window that says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: env is not defined". I've copied the code to run tests in [AngularJS with Jasmine](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/test-filters-in-angularjs). The only difference that I can see is that I'm referencing a CDN. I've got a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6dhu/), with the code posted below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Test Results</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/angular-scenario.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.css" />

    <!-- Load the Test Files-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="e2e/tests.e2e.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="env.execute()">run tests</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The contents of my tests.e2e.js file are in the fiddle. For reference, the code is posted below:

```
'use strict';

describe('MyApp', function() {
    describe('MyPage', function () {
        it('should test', function () {
            expect(true).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can test using [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/v2ZXJ3S9UWn3NSPjXPEk?p=preview). Works as expected.

Jasmine is executed on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
      jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

      var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();

      jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

      jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
        return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
      };

      var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;

      window.onload = function() {
        if (currentWindowOnload) {
          currentWindowOnload();
        }
        execJasmine();
      };

      function execJasmine() {
        jasmineEnv.execute();
      }
    })();
  </script>
```

I hope this will be helpful.